# Discrepances in Bytes Processed from an historical table vs ga_sessions_ historical tables

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

If I extract full data from all existing `ga_sessions_` or `firebase` tables, the **Bytes Processed** are 4.5GB.

If I save the previous query into a Destination Table and then I extract full data from this table, the **Bytes Processed** are 217GB.

Both tables have the same table size. Why this discrepancy?

**UPDATE:**

My `standardSQL` query:

```
SELECT TABLE_SUFFIX AS Date, 
user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, 
user_dim.app_info.app_version, 
user_dim.geo_info.city, 
user_properties.key, 
event.name 
FROM project.dataset.app_events_*, 
UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) AS user_properties, 
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
```

returnes `4.5GB`. If I save this table (called *historical_data*), and I compose this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.historical_data`
```

then it returnes `217GB`.

Comment: 1) when you say extract - do you mean `extract job`? 2) then you mentioned - `previous query` - so is it query or extract? if query - what exactly query is it?

Comment: 1) Extract = Run query. 2) show options -> Destination table (f.ex. `data_historical`) -> Run Query -> Compose query -> Bytes Processed are different higher from SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.data_historical` than 1)

Comment: ok. so both cases are actually queries. without seeing your exact two queries it is hard to answer your question! unless i am still missing something

Comment: SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX AS Date_, user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, user_dim.app_info.app_version, user_dim.geo_info.city, user_properties.key, event.name  FROM `project.dataset.app_events_*`,
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) AS user_properties,
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event

Comment: you should update your question rather :o) as it is hard to consume query text in comments

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible because of double cross joins - for each cross joined row you now have redundant set of below fields

```
TABLE_SUFFIX AS Date, 
user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, 
user_dim.app_info.app_version, 
user_dim.geo_info.city
```

so even though original table was of 4.5GB in size the result got of 217 GB

make sense to me - and this is something that happ[ens with BigData - result can explode to enormous size if not to be careful enough

And, btw, check number of rows in original table vs. output table